# How to send properties with SQL in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two classes, first name is class 1 to collect your name and family addition to your car. This came from another class that name is `car`.

This class (`car`) has two properties, actually I won't get information directly.

For these classes we have two tables as well - first table has relation with class 1, name is qqq and car connected with car.

What's the problem?

In `qqq` table I have column `id_car`. When the customer registers himself, his car id should be stored into the `qqq` table.

I don't know how pass properties with SQL command

Server code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
    public string family { get; set; }
    public car car_id { get; set; }
}

public class car
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String  name { get; set; }
    public String  color { get; set; }
}
```

Client-side code:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlcon;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "insert into cars (name , color) values('BMW','gray');";
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand();
sqlCommand1.Connection = sqlcon;
       
sqlCommand1.CommandText = "insert into qqq (name, family, id_car) values (@name, @family, @car);";

sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", textBox2.Text);
sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", "***MAIN PROBLEM***");
        
sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[image: table qqq]

Comment: I didn't read fully but I think you want to return the primary key of the inserted record. So change the SQL to `insert into qqq (name , family ,id_car) values (@name,@family,@car); SELECT @@IDENTITY` and change the `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: I'd prefer `scope_identity()` instead of `@@identity`, and I'd try to stuff everything into one trip to the DB rather than using multiple connections. But otherwise that is the meat of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the code below. There are also several things here that should be improved, which I will call out via the comments:

```cs
//You can put several statements in one sql string.
string sql = "
    declare @car int;
    insert into cars (name , color) values('BMW','gray');
    set @car = scope_identity();
    insert into qqq (name, family ,id_car) values (@name,@family,@car);";

// Create a new connection object for each call to the database. Really.
// Read this for more info why: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142065/8057
using (var sqlcon = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon))
{ 
    //AddWithValue can cause certain serious performance problems
    // Instead, be specific about the database type and length for the target column.
    // I have to guess here, but you can find this info in your database
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@family", SqlDbtype.NVarChar, 120).Value = textBox2.Text;

    sqlcon.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}  // The connection will be closed and disposed here, even if an exception is thrown.
   // Your original code would have left the connection open if there was an exception.
```

If you want to be really careful, you'll also add a transaction to that SQL. This way if the second part fails the first part can be rolled back and you don't end up accidentally only doing part of the work.

If you still want the new `id_car` value for later use in your application, you can further add a `select @car;` to the end of the SQL string and change `ExecuteNonQuery()` to `ExecuteScalar()` to get the value back.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, you can get the last ID if it is a Identity ID (AUTO_INCREMENT) after insert to the table Car. Then past this ID to the qqq table.
Example:

```
    // for MySQL
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CARS (name , color) VALUES('BMW','gray') OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(@UserId, @GameId)";
    Int32 newId = (Int32) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    // for SQL Server
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CARS (name , color) VALUES('BMW','gray') VALUES(@UserId, @GameId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    int primaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());

    SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand1.Connection = sqlcon;
       
    sqlCommand1.CommandText = "insert into qqq (name , family ,id_car) values (@name,@family,@car);";

    sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox1.Text);
    sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", textBox2.Text);
    sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", newId);  // mysql
    sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", primaryKey); // sql server
```

Comment: yeah man that works exactly , now i want set qqq_id for car while setting car_id ! how can i write it ?